# The process cannot access the file 'path' because it is being used by another process when use FileSystemWatcher

Tags: vb.net

I have trouble creating excel or word files in folders that need to be tracked. If creating continuously using a regular new file right at the home directory trace, it will report an error like this.
I use the filesystemwatcher to keep track of the file

[image]

Here is my code

```
Public Sub Createee(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim x = e.Name
            List1.Add(x)
            Dim path As String = e.FullPath
            Dim i = InStr(path, ".")
            Dim y = InStr(path, "~$")

            If File.Exists(path) Then
                List.Add(path)
            End If

            If path.EndsWith(".txt") Or path.EndsWith(".docx") Or path.EndsWith(".xlsx") Or path.EndsWith(".csv") Then
                If System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) Then
                    LbxWatching.Items.Add(Now.ToLocalTime & " - " & path & " - " & e.ChangeType.ToString)
                    List.Add(path)
                    'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(TbxFrom.Text, TbxTo.Text, True)
                    System.IO.File.Copy(path, TbxTo.Text.ToString & "\" & e.Name, True)
                End If
            End If

            If path.EndsWith(".txt") Or path.EndsWith(".docx") Or path.EndsWith(".xlsx") Or path.EndsWith(".csv") Then
                If i > 0 And y = 0 Then
                    If Not path.Substring(path.Length - 4) = ".tmp" And Not path.Substring(path.Length - 4) = ".TMP" Then
                        LbxWatching.Items.Add(Now.ToLocalTime & " - " & path & " - " & e.ChangeType.ToString)
                        List.Add(path)
                        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(TbxFrom.Text, TbxTo.Text, True)
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(path, TbxTo.Text.ToString & "\" & e.Name, True)
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        List.Clear()
        List1.Clear()
    End Sub

Private Sub FileWatcher_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
            Dim result As String
            For Each result In appsettings
                If result = "Key0" Then
                    TbxFrom.Text = appsettings("Key0")
                ElseIf result = "Key1" Then
                    TbxTo.Text = appsettings("Key1")
                End If
            Next
            MapDrive("X", TbxTo.Text)
            Watcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
            Watcher.Path = TbxFrom.Text
            Watcher.Filter = "*.*"
            Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True

            Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName

            AddHandler Watcher.Changed, AddressOf Modify
            AddHandler Watcher.Created, AddressOf Createee
            AddHandler Watcher.Deleted, AddressOf Delete
            AddHandler Watcher.Renamed, AddressOf ChangeName

            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

            LbxWatching.Items.Clear()
            List = New ArrayList()
            List1 = New ArrayList()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This only happens when I create files in the monitoring folder, other things like editing, deleting files, or copying a bunch of files from elsewhere are not corrupted.

Comment: A file may be locked by the app that creates it, or it may be created on disc, but not written to entirely (so still locked again). It's standard behavior. -- Remove `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`, that's a really bad idea. If you want the events to rise in the UI Thread, set the [FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject) to the instance of your Form (hence `Watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me`).

Comment: @Jimi, if you adds a `FileSystemWatcher` to a form in the designer, I believe that the `SynchronizingObject` is set to that form by default. I haven't tested that recently but it certainly used to be the case. Actually, I just tested and it is indeed the case.

Comment: @Jimi still not working ...

Comment: @KhoaHoàng, if you wouldn't create and configure a `TextBox` in code, why do so for a `FileSystemWatcher`? Add it to the form in the designer and configure it there, including adding/creating the event handlers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, if you drop a component on a Form, not if you create the object in code, as the OP is doing: then `SynchronizingObject` is null (that's why they're setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`). @Khoa Hoàng That's not a *solution*, it's a general indication: never do that. MS Word locks the working files on disc. Not the only app tat does that.

Comment: @Jimi, *"not if you create the object in code"*. Exactly. That's my point: it should not be created in code.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1IuX66y.png , When running, the default text box will have a path like this, I cannot show all the code because it is too long

Comment: @jmcilhinney Why? That's common stuff, you do it all the time with this and other components/controls. Setting the Property is enough, so... instead of the designer.vb file it's set somewhere else, same thing. Also, you don't necessarily have to link a FileSystemWatcher to a Form, the SynchronizationContext can be provided with other means.

Comment: *"still not working"*. That would be because you haven't done anything relevant to the issue. As Jimi said, you're trying to open a file that is already open in another application. The `Created` event is raised when the file is first created. The application that created it may have lots more work to do on that file before it releases it. You can't really know if the file is locked so all you can do is try to open it and catch the exception. It's then up to you what to do. Either give up and move on or wait a while and try again.

Comment: @KhoaHoàng, who's "you"? How about you start using people's names if a comment is directed to them? How about you be specific about what you don't understand? We don't want to waste our time explaining stuff you do already understand so be specific about what you don't. Also, there's more to life than YouTube. If that's all you're using to learn then you're not really trying.

Comment: @Jimi, why would you not? Why would you write loads of error-prone code when you can generate it with a few clicks in the designer? Do you create and configure all your controls in code? I would wager not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What error-prone code? When you drop a component on a Form, all that the CodeDomSerializer does is adding `EnableRaisingEvents = true` and `SynchronizingObject = this/Me`. -- As already mentioned, there isn't any *obbligation* to use a Form as marshaller, you can build a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, or derive the SynchronizationContext in many different ways. Using the ToolBox Component is only a quick way to add it to a specific Form (something I've never done, that's not the way I use it: using a Form as direct marshaller for these events is not a good idea either).

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried everything with FileStream, asynchronous, changing the way of copying files ... and the last thing is thanks to the help here. thanks for help

Comment: @Jimi, *"What error-prone code?"*. The error-prone code the OP posted in their question.

Comment: @KhoaHoàng, none of that is of any use because you can't open a file that is locked by another application, as you have already been told several times. It doesn't matter how you try to open it. You need to wait until the app that created it releases it. That's what you need to think about and research how to do. You haven't tried that yet so you haven't failed, so there isn't any specific reason to think that you can't do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney If I wait a while then it never fails, what if I turn it off suddenly, will the new creation be successful or not?

Comment: As always, think about what you would do if it was a manual action you were performing. If there was no way to determine whether the action would fail, you would just do it and then clean up if it failed, wait a while and try again. That's what you should do here. You can do some actual testing to see how long it usually takes for the file to be available and use that as your wait time. For instance, you might try every 200 milliseconds and then give up if it fails five times. You might start by waiting 500 milliseconds and then double it each time, giving up after ten tries. Etc.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried it a while ago, and this number is quite random, sometimes very quickly sometimes for a few minutes, what happens to it?

Comment: @jmcilhinney if debugging, error will not appear , opposite.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The problem with the code the OP is showing is not, in any way, determined by not (blindly) using a Component (which does nothing for you actually, except linking the FSW to a Form, something you really shouldn't do). Besides trying to access locked files, the problem is that the processing of these files and a whole copy procedure, is performed **inside the event handlers** <- this destroys every good intention and any *hope* of making this work. No component dropped on a Form can save your code if you don't know what you're doing.